# Как отфильтровать объекты? Find, some

Tags: javascript

Есть массивы объектов item, first, second. Item - общий пул сущностей, first - карточки из общего пула отфильтрованные по первому фильтру, second - аналогично first, только отфильтровано все по второму фильтру. Мне надо создать новый массив и внести в него объекты, которые отфильтрованы одновременно по двум фильтрам. Сижу битый час, ничего не получится, прошу о помощи. Единственное до чего дошла :

```
let check = item.find((card) => first.includes(card)? first : null || second.includes(card)? second : null);
```

И оно не работает

Comment: Тут не указан самый важный нюанс, а именно "содержат ли эти три массива ссылки на одни и те же объекты"... В том случае если объекты с идентичными свойствами являются разными экземплярами (например, если фильтрованные выборки API возвращает "на лету" создавая объекты из своих данных), задача весьма некисло усложняется: потребностью в "стабильном" сериализаторе js-объектов для их сравнения (`JSON.stringify` таким сериализатором не является, в плане сравнения он ненадежен).

Comment: ...хотя можно и другим путем пойти, заменяя лишние клоны на референсы объектов (рекурсивная проверка), хз что будет эффективнее по факту. Ну а если экземпляры объектов одни и те же, то элементарно решается через преобразование одного массива (`first` или `second`) в `Set` и пробежкой методом `filter` по второму массиву, как Qwertiy показал в ответе (это самое лучшее решение имхо, хоть и самое очевидное).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, лучше было сделать одну фильтрацию и всё раскидать по 3 массивам сразу:

```
var first = [], second = [], both = []

for (var x of items) {
  var a = f1(x), b = f2(x)

  if (a) {
    first.push(x)
    b && both.push(x)
  }

  b && second.push(x)
}
```

Если так нельзя, то с линейной асимптотикой делается так:

```
var b = new Set(second)
var both = first.filter(x => b.has(x))
```

Если массив небольшой и устраивает (или предпочтительна) квадратичная асимптотика, то можно

```
var both = first.filter(x => second.includes(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

Если везде одни и те же объекты, а не их копии, тогда вроде бы достаточно так:

```js
const firstAndSecond = first.filter(item => second.includes(item));
```